# Android Studio 1.3 not generating signed APK, but does for a different (blank) project

Tags: android

I searched throughly but I am admittedly a newbie when it comes to this IDE. I have spent hours at this stage and I'm unsure if it's a stability bug or something with the build settings.

I made an App, throughout the process I was able to generate the signed APK but due to naming violations on the play store I was forced to rename it, in the process of changing the project name something has broken the ability to generate a signed APK on this specific app.

PROCESS- I select the release options (in contrast to debug) and press build, the event log states- "Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]" but does not generate a signed APK (I've looked in my selected destination and also in the /app/build/output folder).

When I open a relatively blank project and generate signed APK, it makes the apk. I've been through all the settings that I can find, to no avail. I've restarted and reinstalled AS.

Comment: If you select build->generate signed APK, you be taken through an APK generator wizard, which will ask you to enter an APK destination folder. Are you seeing this?

Comment: Yes, say if I select the Desktop as destination, when I reach the final step and press finish, the event log says- "Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]" but it doesn't seem to do anything and the APK is not sent to the desktop. Strangely, the next time I run the project in the emulator, I get a window saying it has been generated "Reveal in Finder..." but it definitely doesnt make the APK.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. I had to open `build/outputs/lint-results-release-fatal.html` and correct the errors shown there. Then the APK was generated successfully.

It is likely a bug on Android Studio parsing lint output.